# Excel: Count strings occurrences in range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, summary

I am quite new to Excel formulas and I am stuck on something. Let's say I have this table:

[image]

What formula can sum all strings to number of occurrences in each column, something like this:

[image]

The result does not have to be in this exact format, but should be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format layout

In `A9`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$7,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(A$8:A8,A$2:A$7),0),0))&"","")
```

In `B9`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A9="","",COUNTIF(A$2:A$7,A9))
```

Then, select `A9:B13` >> copy/paste to `C9:D13`

[image]

Comment: Maybe I did somthing wrong, but I can't work it out as expected. Your formulas only count the first name (e.g John), but I can't do it for all the other names...